# Upper bounds for $ES(n)$ from the first proof of Erdos and Székeres (1935)

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I'm studying the proof of Erdos and Székeres, from 1935. Both proofs are quite clear to me, specially the second (geometric) one, as its bounds on $ES(n)$. However, I can not see which bounds were found for $ES(n)$ in the first proof.

Could someone give me a hand clarifying it, please?

The original paper from Erdos and Székeres can be found [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HXKkfl4BMF3j7WdsBo5gjCrIBTLxs9wO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: $ES(n)$ is not good notation for the quantity we're trying to bound, because the name Székeres does not begin with the letter S; it begins with [the letter Sz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sz_(digraph)#Hungarian). The notation $\operatorname{ESz}(n)$ would be better.

Comment: (Also, though I made the same mistake by copying and pasting, there's no accented letter in Szekeres.)

Answer (score 0):

The bounds from the first proof are not immediately clear, because they depend on a second theorem: the hypergraph Ramsey theorem. That theorem says:

> For all integers $i$, $k\ge i$, and $l\ge i$ there is an integer $m = m_i(k,l)$ with the following property. Whenever all the $i$-element subsets of an $m$-element set are colored red or blue, we can find either
>
> 1. A $k$-element subset such that all the $i$-element subsets within it are red, or
> 2. An $l$-element subset such that all the $i$-element subsets within it are blue.

The bound on $\operatorname{ESz}(n)$ obtained from the first proof is $m_4(5,n)$. The argument is that we let our set be a set of at least $m_4(5,n)$ points in the plane, color a $4$-element subset blue if its points form a convex quadrilateral, and red otherwise.  By the hypergraph Ramsey theorem, there must either be a $5$-element subset whose $4$-element subsets are all red, or an $n$-element subset whose $4$-element subsets are all blue. The first case is impossible: any set of $5$ points contains $4$ that form a convex quadrilateral. Therefore the second case must be true, and the set of $n$ points we find will form a convex $n$-gon.

But now we need to figure out how big $m_4(5,n)$ is.

The good news is that we've reduced the problem to a more well-known and well-studied problem. The bad news is that the bounds we get are going to be  terrible. You can look at a few of the bounds referenced in section 1.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05767); we know that $m_4(5,n) \le 2^{2^{O(n^3 \log n))}}$, and it's conjectured that $m_4(5,n) \ge 2^{2^{\Omega(n)}}$. So we are getting doubly-exponential upper bounds from the first proof: much worse than the singly-exponential bounds from the second proof!